# No warnings when accessing index 4 of int (*foo)[3]

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, compiler-warnings

In the code below I am surprised `gcc` does not warn me about the index. What is the reason for that?

```
int foo[3] = {1,2,3};
int (*bar)[3];

int main(void) {
    bar = &foo;
    foo[42] = 42;
    (*bar)[42] = 42;
    return 0;
}
```

I only get an error for `foo` not for `bar`. Why?

```
$ gcc -std=c99 -Wall -O2 -Wpedantic -Wextra test.c
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6:8: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
     foo[42] = NOPE;
        ^
```

**Note**

I could have written `bar = foo` and declared `bar` as `int* bar`, but I did not and I don't know why... Is one solution better than the other, this is another interesting question.

Comment: A pointer is just a memory address. It is not some high level object that knows it's bounds and what values it's allowed to take.  The compiler had no way of knowing if you actually want to point to the next memory location past foo[3]. Nor any other location. You can assign whatever value you want to a pointer. It's up to you too name sure what it points to is something valid.

Comment: clang 3.9.0 warns for both cases here. IMO it's a compiler bug, because `bar` is an array of 3 pointers exactly as `foo` is an array of 3 `int`s

Comment: @MichaelWalz `bar` is a pointer to an array of 3 `int`, not an array of 3 pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you comment the `foo` access it shows the warning on the `bar` access so it seems it is just a case of `gcc` not showing you the same warning twice.

Whether or not they should be be classified as the same warning that's another matter - seeing how on one hand there are two variables of different types, but on the other hand they alias the same memory. But it seems pretty reasonable to me. Worst case scenario you do an extra compilation until you fix both of them.

```
int foo[3] = {1,2,3};
int (*bar)[3];

int main()
{
    bar = &foo;
    // foo[42] = 42;
    (*bar)[42] = 42; // warning
    return 0;
}
```

```
20 : warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
(*bar)[42] = 42;
~~~~~~~~~^
```

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I realized that both warnings don not show only when both the array indexes are the same, i.e., 42 for both foo and bar.
If you change the indexes to different values it seems to show all the warnings. foo1 and bar1 below are defined exactly like foo and bar.

```
bar = &foo;
bar1 = &foo1;
foo[10] = NOPE;
(*bar)[10] = NOPE;
(*bar1)[11] = NOPE;
 foo1[12] = NOPE;
```

As bar is pointing to foo, and the gcc has already shown a warning for the same address, it does not bother to show the same warning for the bar, if the indexes are the same. And vice versa. Here, the warning shows for foo, bar1 and foo1, and not bar.

Hope this was a plausible explanation.

Comment: You actually figured out what is happening. I just took your ideea and reworded it in a more clear and simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers don't carry size information so the compiler has no way of detecting that out of bounds access.

Comment: Wrong, `bar` is an array of 3 pointers. BTW clang 3.9.0 warns for both cases here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz You're right, my C knowledge is a bit rusty and I've misread the definition. But in that case do you have any clue why gcc can't report the second out of bounds access?

Comment: @Michael - `bar` is a pointer to an array[3] of int.  If you can't read the declaration, consider `bar = &foo`, which would be an error in your interpretation.

Comment: @erdeszt well, gcc _should_ report a warning.

Comment: You would be right if the access was `bar[42]`. But it's in fact `(*bar)[24]`. It's first dereferenced and then indexed, and the dereferenced type is `int[3]` which **does** carry the size information. @MichaelWalz gcc actually does report warnings for this case. Here it was just hidden by the first warning. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that GCC doesn't retain and use the size information of the pointer-to-array, even though it will complain about the incompatible types at `bar=&foo` if you change the number of elements in `bar`:

```
int foo[3] = {1,2,3};
int (*bar)[4];

int main(void) {
    bar = &foo;
}
```

```
39893471.c: In function ‘main’:
39893471.c:5:9: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     bar = &foo;
         ^
```

I confirm this behaviour on GCC versions 4.8 and 6.1.

N.B. the `-O2` argument is required for `-Warray-bounds` to work; this caught me out for a while!

Comment: hold your horses on the bug report. See my answer.